# loop over next sequence and assign a variable

Tags: bash

I have those 4 for loops

```
for list in 11 12 1 ; do
        if [[ $list =~ "$MONTH" ]] ; then
                QUARTER=Q1
        fi
done
```

## #

```
for list in 2 3 4 ; do
        if [[ $list =~ "$MONTH" ]] ; then
                QUARTER=Q2
        fi
done
```

## #

```
for list in 5 6 7 ; do
        if [[ $list =~ "$MONTH" ]] ; then
                QUARTER=Q3
        fi
done
```

## #

```
for list in 8 9 10 ; do
        if [[ $list =~ "$MONTH" ]] ; then
                QUARTER=Q4
        fi
done
```

Checking if the current month exists in the list and assigning the right QUARTER.

Do you have a shorter or elegant to achieve it ?

Comment: `(( QUARTER = ( (MONTH + 1) / 3 ) % 4 + 1 ))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an array that maps from the month number to the name of the quarter:

```
quarters=(- Q1 Q2 Q2 Q2 Q3 Q3 Q3 Q4 Q4 Q4 Q1 Q1)
QUARTER="${quarters[MONTH]}"
```

(This only works if `$MONTH` is a non–zero-padded integer between 1 and 12; but your existing code already behaves rather oddly if that's not the case, so I'm assuming that's fine?)

Answer (score 1):

Use arithmetic expansion.

```
QUARTER=Q$(( (MONTH + 13) % 12 / 3 + 1))
```

1. Adding 13 and taking the remainder from 12 "rotates" the months into the correct groups of 3.
2. Dividing by 3 lumps each consecutive group of 3 into the same quarter.
3. Adding 1 to the quarter compensates for the months being numbered from 1, not 0.